# homotopy cofibers (Thom spaces)

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

I have a problem with understanding the construction which I marked as the red ractangle. The whole concept is showing the alternative definition of a Thom space. Construction up to the second diagram is more or less clear, some of doubts I put into another question. Here I stuck on the last diagram. What role plays the "star" (*)? Also the sentence with 'zig-zag of weak equivalences' is completly incomprehensible to me.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A zig-zag of weak equivalences is a sequence of maps $A\xrightarrow{\simeq} B\xleftarrow{\simeq}C\xrightarrow{\simeq}\dots$, each of which is a weak equivalence, in that it induces isomorphisms on $\pi_*$. The maps don't all point in the same direction, so although you know is that each space in the zig-zag has the same homotopy groups, there may be no direct map $A\rightarrow C$ that induces the isomorphism. This is particularly useful, say, in the case that you can appeal to Whitehead's theorem.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't clear enough, my mistake :) I guess what such a zig-zag could be, my problem is that I don't know what is means to take 'homotopy cofibers of columns' and then, how the zig-zag is built. I know the definition of cofibration and so on, but my intuition is not enough in this case. Too much knowledge to catch it and imagine.

Comment: If $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration, then its cofiber $C_i\simeq X/A$ has a well-defined homotopy type in that if $X\simeq X'$, $A\simeq A'$ are homotopy equivalences then $X/A\simeq X'/A'$. If $i$ is not a cofibration then this does not necessarily hold. To get the homotopy cofiber of an arbitray map $f:X\rightarrow Y$, first convert it to a cofbration $\overline f:M_f\hookrightarrow Y$, say using a mapping cylinder, and then take the ordinary cofiber of this cofibration. The resulting homotopy type is independent of the particular choices of $M_f$, $\overline f$.